# MySQL Query for current year sales by month and previous years sales by month

Tags: mysql

How can I get the net sales for last year by month also?
  I am trying to report current month sales info with the related increase/decrease percentages.

```
select date_format(sdate,'%M-%Y') as sdate,     
    sum(netsales) as 'netsales',  
    from repsoft.daily  
    where scode=1234 and year(sdate)=year('2016-06-01')  
    group by month(sdate)  
    order by month(sdate);
```

Comment: Can you add more details, like a table sample and the results of your tries?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you group it by year as well?

```
select date_format(sdate,'%M-%Y') as sdate,     
    sum(netsales) as 'netsales',  
    from repsoft.daily  
    where scode=1234 and year(sdate)=year('2016-06-01')  
    group by year(sdate), month(sdate)  
    order by year(sdate), month(sdate);
```